# Populate All Rows with Values with Formula

Tags: excel, vba, finance

I was hoping to get help with one last tweak to this code. It works just fine with two extra manual steps, but I would love to make it all automatic with the Macros. In the last paragraph, there is a formula that I would like to be included in as many rows as there are rows with values in them, not just until Row 244.

```
Sub GLMacro2()
' Shortcut Ctrl+Shift+H
    Range("A1").Select
    ActiveCell.SpecialCells(xlLastCell).Select
    Rows(ActiveCell.Row).Delete
    Range("N1").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "Balance"
    Columns("A:N").Select
    Columns("A:N").EntireColumn.AutoFit
    Range("A1").Select
    Columns("B:B").Select
    Selection.ColumnWidth = 12
    Columns("C:C").Select
    Selection.ColumnWidth = 12
    Columns("H:H").Select
    Selection.ColumnWidth = 42.57
    Range("A1").Select
    Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlToRight)).Select
    Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlDown)).Select
    Selection.Sort Key1:=Range("G2"), Order1:=xlAscending, Header:=xlGuess, _
        OrderCustom:=1, MatchCase:=False, Orientation:=xlTopToBottom, _
        DataOption1:=xlSortNormal
    Selection.Subtotal GroupBy:=7, Function:=xlSum, TotalList:=Array(12, 13), _
        Replace:=False, PageBreaks:=False, SummaryBelowData:=True
    With ActiveSheet.Outline
        .AutomaticStyles = False
        .SummaryRow = xlBelow
        .SummaryColumn = xlLeft
    End With
    Selection.ApplyOutlineStyles
    Columns("L:N").Select
    Selection.Style = "Comma"
    Range("A1").Select
    Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlToRight)).Select
    With Selection.Interior
        .ColorIndex = 49
        .Pattern = xlSolid
    End With
    Selection.Font.ColorIndex = 2
    Selection.Font.Bold = True
    Range("A1").Select
' Balance
    ActiveCell.Offset(1, 13).Range("A1").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=IF(ISBLANK(C[-3]),RC[-2]-RC[-1],"""")"
    ActiveCell.Select
    Selection.AutoFill Destination:=ActiveCell.Range("A1:A244"), Type:= _
        xlFillDefault
    ActiveCell.Range("A1:A2").Select
    ActiveCell.Columns("A:A").EntireColumn.EntireColumn.AutoFit
    Selection.Style = "Comma"
End Sub
```

Comment: What have you tried so far? It looks like this is just copy & paste from the macro recorder.  You simply need to define a `Range` variable to represent the varying length of that column, and use that instead of `ActiveCell.Range("A1:A244")`.

Answer (score 1):

Use a code similar to this:

```
Dim RowCount as Long

RowCount = Cells(Rows.Count,2).End(xlUp).Row 
'Will get the row of the last row. Replace 2 with what ever column you want it to be bassed off. Ex: B = 2
```

Then in your auto-fill, what you want to do it this:

```
Selection.AutoFill Destination:=ActiveCell.Range("A1:A" & RowCount), Type:= _
    xlFillDefault
```